# Create Comma Seperated List from MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a list of users in my table.  How would I go about taking that list and returning it as one PHP variable with each user name separated by a comma?

Answer (score 7):

You could generate a comma-separated list with a query:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(username) FROM MyTable
```

Or else you could fetch rows and join them in PHP:

```
$sql = "SELECT username FROM MyTable";
$stmt = $pdo->query($sql);
$users = array();
while ($username = $stmt->fetchColumn()) {
    $users[] = $username;
}
$userlist = join(",", $users);
```

Comment: Of course, the usual warning: `GROUP_CONCAT()` is length-limited, usually to 1024 characters. Any additional data after that is silently dropped.

Answer (score 2):

You would [fetch the list from the database](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlselect.php), store it in [an array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), then [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) it.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I was able to figure this out was by storing the results from each col, or field, and then echoing the implode:

```
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) //store the result               
      $cols = array(); //instantiate an array
      while($col = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
          $cols[] = $col['username']; //step through results and save each username in array
      }
      echo implode(",",$cols); //turn the array into a comma separated string and echo it
```

This took me a while to figure out exactly how to do this. Hope it helps!